# Change the default Junk Email folder in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

An old junk mail filter program I used to use created a junk email folder. When I moved from Outlook 2003 to 2007, Outlook created a new folder called Junk Email1. Now, after our move to a new Exchange server, I now have a "Junk Email" folder and the existing "Junk Email1" folder. Is there a way to change the default Outlook Junk Email folder back to "Junk Email"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To quickly reset all predefined folder names:**

Open Start → Run (or Command Prompt). Run this command:

```
reg add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook\Setup" /v ResetFolderNames /t reg_dword /d 1 /f
```

Alternatively:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE12\outlook" /resetfoldernames
```

Different sources list both methods. I haven't tried any of them.

- [XCLN: Names of Mailbox Folders Appear in Different Languages](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=188856)
- [OL2002: Additional Command-Line Switches](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=296192)
- [Reset Mailbox Language](http://www.petri.co.il/reset_mailbox_language.htm)

---

**To rename a single folder:**

1. Rename the currently existing "Junk E-mail" to something else.
2. Install [Microsoft CDO](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2714320d-c997-4de1-986f-24f081725d36).
3. In Outlook, open *Tools → Macro → **Visual Basic Editor***.
4. In the Visual Basic window, open *Tools → **References***, and enable the "Microsoft CDO 1.2.1" entry. (Click OK.)
5. In the VB window's left-side tree, open *Project1 → Microsoft Office Outlook → **ThisOutlookSession***
6. Paste the following script (originally from Microsoft [KB831363](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=831363)) and run it.

---

```
Sub CDORenameFolder()
    Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim outlookSession As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim cdoSession As MAPI.Session
    Dim folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim cdoFolder As MAPI.folder
    Dim newName As String

    Set outlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set outlookSession = outlookApp.Session
    Set cdoSession = New MAPI.Session
    cdoSession.Logon ShowDialog:=False, NewSession:=False

    Set folder = outlookSession.PickFolder
    Set cdoFolder = cdoSession.GetFolder(folder.EntryID, folder.StoreID)

    newName = InputBox(("Rename '" + cdoFolder.Name + "' to:"), "Rename folder", cdoFolder.Name)
    If newName <> "" Then
        cdoFolder.Name = newName
        cdoFolder.Update
    End If

    cdoSession.Logoff
    Set cdoSession = Nothing
    Set outlookSession = Nothing
    Set outlookApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: The first suggestion doesn't work. I'll the other one later.

Comment: Okay, I ran it and it changed the folder name. Only time will tell if it works. Will mark as answer after it has been confirmed.

Comment: Did this issue recur Mike? Have the same issue with a user and Kaspersky Anti-Spam and it recurs after repairing the PST & Resetting folders & Resetting folder names (2 different outlook flags). Tempted to throw it at Kaspersky Support! :)